# Pressure Fermenting an IPA, how long and at what pressure?

Tags: techniques

I'm using a FermZilla Fermenter I plan on using a pressure fermentation method.
This will be the first time doing this I would to get some advice from those who have done this.

length of time under pressure?
Temperature while under pressure?

Comment: What is the mean pressure used, < 1 bar < 15psi (>12 psi < 15psi)

Answer (score 2):

First let me state that I don't have a FermZilla and do not know how much pressure one of those can take safely. Verify it can handle it before you do it. Ok disclaimer out of the way…

I typically will ferment at 6 to 10 psi during the first 2/3 to 3/4 of “active” fermentation (usually about 3 to 5 days depending on the recipe and yeast). Then for the last bit will ramp it up to 13-14 psi. This allows there to be a decent amount of carbonation when it is done. I still let it sit for a week in the fridge at serving pressure (12-13 psi) to finish it up.

I’ve found that the higher the pressure the slower the fermentation and above 15 psi it starts to produce some off flavors. Temperature wise I used to do 65F and then a ramp to 68F to have the yeast clean up after themselves. Since using pressure I’ve been doing about 5 degrees warmer. I’m told that I can go higher but I’ve been conservative.

Hope this helps